# Change cell table into text box when clicked

Tags: javascript, html-table, onclick

I'm having trouble with my code. The text area should appear when a user clicks on a cell table. The text area appears when it is clicked but it always appears on the first cell. I want the text area to appear exactly where the cell appears. (The values in the table are retrieved from a database)..

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['key']))
{
    header("location:index.php");   
}

    include"connect.php";?>
   <html>
    <head>
       <title>All Records</title>   
       <style>
        table{ text-align:justified;}
        a {text-decoration:none;
           color:black;
        }
        .replace {display:none;}
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function exchange(el){
        var ie=document.all&&!document.getElementById? document.all : 0;
        var toObjId=/b$/.test(el.id)? el.id.replace(/b$/,'') : el.id+'b';
        var toObj=ie? ie[toObjId] : document.getElementById(toObjId);

        if(/b$/.test(el.id))  
        toObj.innerHTML=el.value;
        else{
        toObj.style.width=el.offsetWidth+7+'px';
        toObj.value=el.innerHTML;
        }
        el.style.display='none';
        toObj.style.display='inline';
        }
      </script>
</head>
   <body>


   <?php 
     echo "<table border=1 id='records' >";
     echo "<tr><th class='data' rowspan='2' ><strong>EMPLOYEE</strong></th>";
     echo "<th class='data' rowspan='2'>DATE</th>
                <th colspan='2'>AM</th>
                <th colspan='2'>PM</th>
                <th colspan='2'>OVERTIME</th></tr>";
     echo "<tr>
        <th>Arrival</th>
        <th>Departure</th>  
        <th>Arrival</th>
        <th>Departure</th>
        <th>In</th>
        <th>Out</th>
       </tr>";


   $query="SELECT 
   employee_detail.employee_code,
   employee_detail.lname,
   employee_detail.fname,
   employee_detail.mname,
   employee_record.date,
   employee_record.am_in,
   employee_record.am_out,
   employee_record.pm_in,
   employee_record.pm_out,
   employee_record.over_in,
   employee_record.over_out
   FROM employee_detail INNER JOIN employee_record ON
   employee_record.employee_code=employee_detail.employee_code ORDER BY id DESC ";

   $result=mysql_query($query);
   $affected=mysql_affected_rows();

   while($affected>=1&&$row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
     echo '<tr><td><a href="edit.php?id2='.$row['employee_code'].'" name="edit">';
     echo $row['lname'].",&nbsp";
     echo $row['fname']."&nbsp";
     echo $row['mname']."</a></td>"; 
     echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
     echo '<td><span id="itm1" onclick="exchange(this);">'.$row['am_in'].'</span>                  
     <textarea ondblclick="exchange(this);" id="itm1b" class="replace" type="text" 
     value='.$row['am_in'].'></textarea></td>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['am_out'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['pm_in'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['pm_out'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['over_in'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['over_out'].'</td>';
     $affected--;
   }     
     echo "</tr></table>";
   ?>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the first `<textarea>` is always the one that appears makes it sound like your code is functioning properly, but because you're generating multiple elements with identical `id` attributes, it's targeting the first matching element instead of the one nearest where you click.

Make each `id` unique (which is actually a requirement for validity) by appending that result's 'employee_code' value (which is presumably a primary key in the database):

```
    echo '<td>';

    echo   '<span id="itm"' . $row['employee_code'] . '" ';
    echo   'onclick="exchange(this);">';
    echo   $row['am_in'];
    echo   '</span>';

    echo   '<textarea ondblclick="exchange(this);" id="itm';
    echo   $row['employee_code'] . 'b" class="replace" type="text" ';
    echo   'value=' . $row['am_in'] . '>';
    echo   '</textarea>'

    echo '</td>';
```

Comment: @user1758736 RE: your 'answer' below - `id` attributes must begin with a letter: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: sorry for that...i have another question, can i pass  the php values to a variable then assign that variable to be the id of span and textarea? thanks for answering my questions...

Comment: The 2nd and 6th-7th lines in the above code block should result in element `id`s of "itm1234" and "itm1234b" respectively, where the `employee_code` is "1234". There shouldn't be a need to pass the php value to a separate variable, because you are directly outputting HTML markup. If you would prefer to use some other values, just replace the `$row['employee_code']` in those two locations with the name of the variable you want to use.

Comment: i tried to add the code you've given, but i'm getting no results..the cell doesn't change into a textarea after it has been clicked..Can u tell me why? (sorry if i'm annoying..i'm annoyed by myself too ^^,)

Comment: i have tried another method to this but i'm also having trouble with it. Can you take a look at it? thanks [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004833/how-to-exit-text-box-after-clicking-outside-the-cell)

Answer (score 0):

can i use a php value as the id of the span and the text area instead?

```
  echo '<td>';
  echo   '<span id='.$row['employee_code'] . ' onclick="exchange(this);">'.$row['am_in'].'</span>';
  echo '<textarea ondblclick="exchange(this);" id='.$row['employee_code']. ' class="replace" type="text" value=' . $row['am_in'] .' >'. $row['am_in'] . '</textarea>';
  echo '</td>
```