# how to exit text box after clicking outside the cell

Tags: javascript, textbox, exit-code

I accidentally found this code on the web and it has solved most of my problem, however there is one thing that i want to add to this code but i don't know how my question is, how can i exit the textbox after a user has double clicked it or after the user has finished editing it?

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    function INPUT(id){
    var obj=document.getElementById(id),tds=obj.getElementsByTagName('TD'),z0=0,ip,html;
    for (;z0<tds.length;z0++){
    tds[z0].onmouseup=function(){ AddInput(this); }
    }
    }

    function AddInput(td){
    var ip=zxcAddField('INPUT','text','');
    ip.value=td.innerHTML;
    td.innerHTML='';
    td.appendChild(ip);
    td.onmouseup=null;
    }

    function zxcAddField(nn,type,nme){
    var obj;
    try {
    obj=document.createElement('<'+nn+' name="'+(nme||'')+'" '+(type?'type="'+type+'" ':'')+' >');
    }
    catch(error){
    obj=document.createElement(nn);
    if (type){
    obj.type=type;
    }
    obj.name=nme||'';
    }
    return obj;
    }


    /*]]>*/
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    function Init(){
    INPUT('tst');
    }

    if (window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('load',Init, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent){
    window.attachEvent('onload',Init);
    }

    /*]]>*/
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table id="tst" border="1">
    <tr width="200">
    <td>some html</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by exit the textbox?

Comment: thanks for the reply...when the user has finished editing the value in textbox, the textbox should disappear and the edited text will only appear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, modify `AddInput` in order to set a listener for the *blur* event, which will fire when something other than the element in question receives a click:

```
function AddInput(td){
    var ip=zxcAddField('INPUT','text','');
    ip.value=td.innerHTML;
    ip.onblur = function () { removeInput(ip); };
    td.innerHTML='';
    td.appendChild(ip);
    td.onmouseup=null;
}
```

Then, you can add a new `removeInput` function, which will replace the `<td>`'s content when the `<input>` fires its *blur* event:

```
function removeInput(input) {
    var val = input.value;
    var td = input.parentNode;
    td.removeChild(td.lastChild);
    td.innerHTML = val;
    td.onmouseup = function () { AddInput(td); };
}
```

This function also reassigns a *mouseup* event listener, since it gets set to `null` in the `AddInput` function.

Keep in mind that while this worked for me in Chrome 22, it will probably require a bit of extra effort to test and fix whatever cross-browser issues might exist with inline event and attribute assignments.

If it were my code, I'd probably rewrite the 'standard' version using `addEventListener` and `getAttribute()` / `setAttribute()`, and then make a remedial IE-only path using its equivalents. Or, just use jQuery and let it do all the cross-browser stuff for you.

Comment: hi again! the codes you provide were really helpful..so, i would like to ask another one if that's okay...i want the cell where the textbox appears to automatically save the new value directly on the database table..i know that this is possible but i don't know how to start thanks again ^^,